# Linq Compound selection

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

How can i combine two arrays in to a single array during compound selection ( **without using Union** ) ( The question was asked at interview).

```
    var num1 = new int[] { 12, 3, 4, 5 };
    var num2 = new int[] { 1, 33, 6, 10 };
```

I tried as

```
    var pairs = from a in num1 from b in num2  select new {combined={a,b}};
```

Expected:
combined need to be {12,3,4,5,1,33,6,10}

Comment: There are any number of ways of combining two arrays. Unless you specify what you want the result to be, it's hard to give an answer.

Comment: Did the interviewer really want you to use Linq?  I would guess they didn't, to see if you can do it by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
num1.Concat( num2 );
```

I'm not sure if there is a related LINQ keyword.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to combine 2 arrays into a new array which contains elements from both arrays then use concat.

```
var combined = num1.Concat(num2);
var combinedAsArray = combined.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Tinister answered first ,May i tick his answer ?

Comment: @linqfying tick the answer you feel is best.  Tinister beat me to the punch so I would tick his.

Answer (score -1):

var newArray = (from number in num1.Concat(num2) select number).ToArray();

Comment: The linq construct does not add anything. 'num1.Concat(num2).ToArray()' is enough.

Comment: I agree it doesn't, but his question asked for a compound selection, which to me would imply a linq construct as opposed to just calling a linq extension method by itself.